# StorageFile Property System.Title "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm combining some images into a bigger image and saving them into a local cache.
When loading them I need to know how many images are combined in the loaded image.

To achieve this I tried to use the image properties and serialize these informations in the title property.
Considering that the user doesn't usually access the cache - and even if they did and changed the title, it wouldn't have any consequences - this seemed to be a reliable way of storing the information.

However, for some reason I get a "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception quite often when trying to save the properties.
It's kind of weird because it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't and I can't really spot a difference between the times it works and the times it doesn't.

Here's the code used to write the properties:

```
private static async Task SaveCountsAsync(StorageFile file, int usedCount, int overallCount)
{
  await file.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(
    new [] {new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.Title", $"{usedCount}-{overallCount}")}
  );
}
```

I've also tried setting the title using the ImageProperties but the error is the same.

**Update:**
I have noticed that the exception only occurs if an image is created by combining multiple images and saved to a file.
If the image is a single image and the image file was just copied, the code works flawless.
I'm using the following line to create the file from the image byte array before trying to save the counts.

```
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, imageBytes);
```

Comment: It seems that you try to add a property with the same name again.

Comment: The properties have fixed names. I'm only overwriting the existing value which is an empty string. See [System.Title](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb787584)

Comment: Could you share a [mcve]? As in my test, it works well.